# Windows server AD replication

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, replication

We have run dcdiag on our Windows server 2003 AD domain controller and replication seems to be down (output below).

```
 Testing server: Tradeston\PNC4SERVER
      Starting test: Replications
         REPLICATION-RECEIVED LATENCY WARNING
         PNC4SERVER:  Current time is 2010-12-03 13:01:57.
            CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=pnc4,DC=local
               Last replication recieved from PNC4DR at 2009-04-06 13:58:21.
               WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
            CN=Configuration,DC=pnc4,DC=local
               Last replication recieved from PNC4DR at 2009-04-06 13:58:21.
               WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
            DC=pnc4,DC=local
               Last replication recieved from PNC4DR at 2009-04-06 13:58:19.
               WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
```

---

We then ran repadmin/showreps and to us it seems like replication is fine (again output below)

```
Tradeston\PNC4SERVER
DC Options: IS_GC 
Site Options: (none)
DC object GUID: 6a3f22f9-9b02-42ad-a35f-aa34dc674d54
DC invocationID: 6a3f22f9-9b02-42ad-a35f-aa34dc674d54

==== INBOUND NEIGHBORS ======================================

DC=pnc4,DC=local
    BorronStreet\PNC4DR via RPC
        DC object GUID: 09648aec-ddef-47b4-bca3-d1a8ab088473
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 12:47:41 was successful.
    Tradeston\PNC4STANDBY via RPC
        DC object GUID: 9bb91810-d7e3-492e-bc6f-6c2a5444f0e1
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 13:05:15 was successful.

CN=Configuration,DC=pnc4,DC=local
    BorronStreet\PNC4DR via RPC
        DC object GUID: 09648aec-ddef-47b4-bca3-d1a8ab088473
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 12:47:41 was successful.
    Tradeston\PNC4STANDBY via RPC
        DC object GUID: 9bb91810-d7e3-492e-bc6f-6c2a5444f0e1
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 13:01:08 was successful.

CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=pnc4,DC=local
    Tradeston\PNC4STANDBY via RPC
        DC object GUID: 9bb91810-d7e3-492e-bc6f-6c2a5444f0e1
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 12:47:41 was successful.
    BorronStreet\PNC4DR via RPC
        DC object GUID: 09648aec-ddef-47b4-bca3-d1a8ab088473
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 12:47:41 was successful.

DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=pnc4,DC=local
    Tradeston\PNC4STANDBY via RPC
        DC object GUID: 9bb91810-d7e3-492e-bc6f-6c2a5444f0e1
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 12:47:41 was successful.
    BorronStreet\PNC4DR via RPC
        DC object GUID: 09648aec-ddef-47b4-bca3-d1a8ab088473
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 12:47:41 was successful.

DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=pnc4,DC=local
    Tradeston\PNC4STANDBY via RPC
        DC object GUID: 9bb91810-d7e3-492e-bc6f-6c2a5444f0e1
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 12:47:41 was successful.
    BorronStreet\PNC4DR via RPC
        DC object GUID: 09648aec-ddef-47b4-bca3-d1a8ab088473
        Last attempt @ 2010-12-03 12:47:41 was successful.
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Is everything looking hunky-dorey in Sites and Services?

Comment: I've had a look thanks - it does not look good.  Our main site has two domain controllers and the NTDS settings on both look fine.  At the second site there are 2 NTDS entries.  One looks fine, the other has the foreign characters below (some kind of GUID?) 
 CNF:59f2b157-43fa-4b46-8036-3977494042c2

Answer (score 2):

Are the times all in sync with the same source;
from command line net time /querysntp and also typing time to verify they are within the limits of diff.

Comment: Vote++.  Ensure you have at least two, preferably three, Reliable Time Sources (RTS) defined in your Domain Controller GPO.

Answer (score 0):

Simple test: Put files with server names in respective sysvol shares to check replication.

Comment: That'll test FRS replication, not AD replication.  Create directory objects (e.g.: a user) to see if AD repl is working.